# Angular SSR Canonicalization

Tags: angular, angular-universal, canonical-link, canonicalization

Am trying to do Angular SSR with canonical URL. AM using the below code, Actually this is working fine with HTTP links. My issue is Canonical url is showing HTTP link and actual my Website is in HTTPS. How to fix this issue..???

```
let link: HTMLLinkElement = this.doc.createElement('link');
        link.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
        this.doc.head.appendChild(link);
        let url = this.doc.URL;
        link.setAttribute('href', url);
```

Comment: `let url = this.doc.URL.replace('http://','https://');` ?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the Exact solution for that. I solved the issue by this small code. I don't know why i did'nt think this replace function.

Answer (score 2):

Works for me

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}

updateCanonical(url: string) {
    const canonicalUrl = this.siteUrl + '/' + url;
    const head = this.document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var element: HTMLLinkElement = this.document.querySelector(`link[rel='canonical']`) || null;
    if (element == null) {
      element = this.document.createElement('link') as HTMLLinkElement;
      head.appendChild(element);
    }
    element.setAttribute('rel', 'canonical');
    element.setAttribute('href', canonicalUrl);
  }
```